# Determine which files a process opened (Linux)

Tags: linux, process, files

I am trying to determine which files a process creates when it runs. I know that I can list the file handles of a currently running process by looking in /proc or using lsof. However, the problem is that the program finishes in less than a second. Is there any way I can get the list of files it opened when it ran? I am using CentOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ strace -e trace=open /path/to/your/program 2>&1 | less
```

Answer (score 3):

Strace

http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace